# Access 2013 Web App List Pane repeating first entry over and over

Tags: ms-access, web-applications

I am working in Access 2013 on a web app. In this app I want the List Pane (searchable menu on the left of listview) to give 4 different types of information, not just the primary and secondary source.

To do this I used the expressions:

"=[CustomerTextBox].Value + " " + [OrderTextBox].Value"   for the primary

and

"=[IDTextBox].Value + " " + [StatusTextBox].Value"    for the secondary.

It shows the information exactly as I want it but the issue is that it repeats the exact same record for all of the records in the list.

Ideally, I would like to tie this directly to the table values instead of the textbox values but the expression builder doesn't give me this option.

This is my first time using Access so I am still learning the "rules" etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use & to join two strings. Also make sure you are using this expression in the "control source" field and not in default value field

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue. It still repeats the first data for all tabs. I only have the option to put this expression in the "Primary" and/or "Secondary" fields. There is no "default value" etc.